# NativeScript : How do we display more tabs with TabView

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a TabView with 20 tabItems, even though there's sufficient space to render about 5 or 6 tabItems only 3 tabs are rendered at a time, as seen here:

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/img/tab-view-image.png

How do we display more? I wonder if it's a configuration or something with css styling?

Comment: If you have more tabs than it could fit in screen, you will have them scrollable on Android and a new More tab will appear in iOS. I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my end, do you a Playground sample?